# Documentum java method server service is getting down automatically in windows server

Tags: windows, tomcat, jboss, middleware

"Documentum java method server service" is getting down automatically in windows server

I can see the "java.exe" is still running in task manager.

As workaround I'm killing the java.exe process and starting JMS service.

Please help me with the root cause of this issue.

Sometimes even if Documentum java method server service is in running state, ACS url
(http://localhost:9080/bpm/outbound_details.jsp) is not working.

Please help me with the root cause of this issue